# how to show the dropdown values to be shown only once in the list using powerapp

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I have a dropdown that shows me some categories and those categories in turn have a list of subcategories

The problem I am having is that certain categories appear repeated, and **I would like to know how I can show the categories, not repeated**

- **Category**

[image]

```
Table1
```

- **Sub Category**

[image]

```
Filter(Table1; CATEGORIES = CategoriesDropdown.SelectedText.CATEGORIES)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you are after the Distinct funciton in Power Apps.

```
Distinct(List/Table Name,ColumnName)
```

Not enterily sure what field you are using to display data in your **Category** dropdown, but generally this is how you'd do it:

```
Distinct(Table1, *Title) //use the column name you want to get the distict values
```

You can also apply the same logic for the Second dropdown

For further reference, [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-distinct) will give you all the details about the Distinct function.

**Note**: Your List/Table could be:

- A Collection
- The Connection Name e.g. your SharePoint list or your SQL table
- A filtered collection/table

> ```
>  Distinct(Filter(Table1, CATEGORIES = CategoriesDropdown.SelectedText.CATEGORIES), ColumnName)
> ```

Hope it helps